# Список подключенных устройств к точке доступа на Android устройстве

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Всем привет! Как можно получить список устройств(mac или id) подключенных к точке доступа на телефоне?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сделать через [WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#public-methods). Например есть метод [WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback#LocalOnlyHotspotCallback()). Из описания к методу:

> Callback class for applications to receive updates about the
> LocalOnlyHotspot status.

Например есть подобный [вопрос тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984345/how-to-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically-in-android-8-0-oreo/45996578#45996578), то есть вы создаете слушатель:

```
 WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    manager.startLocalOnlyHotspot(new WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStarted(WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reservation) {
            super.onStarted(reservation);
            Log.d(TAG, "Wifi Hotspot is on now");
            mReservation = reservation;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            super.onStopped();
            Log.d(TAG, "onStopped: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(int reason) {
            super.onFailed(reason);
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailed: ");
        }
    }, new Handler());
```

и дальше [вот описывается](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290726/android-9-0-wifi-hotspot-api) как можно получить информацию про созданную точку доступа. [Проект для примера](https://github.com/iadeelzafar/spotserve).

Comment: забыл сказать, что проблема на 7 андроиде

Comment: та а какая проблема? вы не предоставили никакого кода, который у вас есть( я сделал просто допущение как можно начинать решать вашу задачу